# Separating methods in the same class, used in a method under test, to allow mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a large method which I've split into several methods and put them in the same class.

Example:

```
public void Method(int param)
{
    var result = this.DoSomething(param);

    this.DoSomethingElse(result);
}
```

But now I can't test this method, since I can't mock the methods inside it, because they are in the class under test.

The smaller methods are reused in the same class, but not outside of it. Is it a good idea to put the them in a different class and supply them as a dependency so that I can mock them?

Or is the method itself not worth testing, and it is enough to test only the smaller methods?

Comment: It possible that your question is a sign that your class under the test violating "Single Responsibility principle". (Class should have only one reason to change). If not, then you should test "bigger" methods and "smaller" methods will be tested through it. So depend on what "smaller" method do - you can decide to move it outside and introduce it as dependency for class under test

Comment: L. Guthardt, I could mock the dependencies that the smaller methods use and thus test the whole method, but I think that would become too confusing and If I change the implementation of the smaller methods, then I would also have to change the tests for the whole method. So, basically it'll result in spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large method which I've split into several methods and put
>   them in the same class.

It's called refactoring ([Extract Method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)) - you are changing the implementation without changing behavior. And that's the main reason why you should not test implementation details. Your tests should not fail when the behavior of class was not changed. That will allow you doing a lot of small refactorings within a class easily - change algorithms, split methods, changing data types which are used internally. And your tests instead of failing will help you to see that behavior is still implemented correctly.

E.g. if you are testing pizzeria, then you don't care how big is their kitchen, who work in that kitchen, and what model of the oven they use. You are interested only in the behavior of the pizzeria - `CookPepperoni()` should return correct pizza of required quality.

> Is it a good idea to put them in a different class

Well, technically that is called a refactoring too - [Extract Class](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html). But here is the definition of [refactoring](https://refactoring.com/) by Martin Fowler:

> *Refactoring is a disciplined technique for restructuring an existing
>   body of code, altering its internal structure without changing its
>   external behavior.*

so, it's a refactoring with a little note - the behavior of system will not change, but the behavior of class under test will change - it should now interact with the external dependency. Like with pizzeria - if you will introduce a dependency to the box factory, then the responsibility of pizzeria will involve taking boxes from the factory. That should be tested with mocks.

Such kind of refactorings will break your tests. Or vice versa - if you are practicing TDD, then you should change your tests to check new expected behavior. Then after tests will fail, you should extract class and make tests green again.

Comment: In the case of the example method which does not return anything. I guess, I can only test that it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @typhon04 I don't think that *not throwing an exception* is a responsibility of this method. I bet it either interacts with some external dependency (write something to console, to file, raise event etc) or changes the state of the class under test. You should verify that

Comment: Correct. It pretty much adds and entry to an object and removes another. And those are the two methods. I can mock the dependencies of the other two methods and verify the changes had happened, but I think I should do that in the tests for those methods. The job of the "bigger" method is to call correctly the other two, which I guess is an implementation detail which I should not test. Which leaves me with nothing to test. Perhaps, the method itself does not do enough to be a method on its own and should be removed.

Comment: @typhon04 you are not testing a method body - you are testing interface of the class - there is a public method called `Method` which accepts one integer parameter. Pretend that you don't know how this method is implemented and write a test for this method *without* knowing what is inside.

Answer (score 1):

The common way is that you create a different class where you define these smaller methods. Then in your main class you create an instance of this different class to call its methods. For example this different class is called `ClassSmallMethods` (you should pick something more suitable). Then in your main class you create the instance of the other class:

```
ClassSmallMethods ClassInstance = new ClassSmallMethods();
```

Let´s pretend there is a method called `public string ReturnString()` in your class `ClassSmallMethods` that returns a `string`. Now you can call this method and for exmaple get the value which the method returns. (or do whatever you want to do with the method):

```
string randomString;
randomString = ClassInstance.ReturnString();
```

Comment: I understand how It can be done. The question is should it be done. The plus sides of introducing another class is that I split the dependencies and I have a better control over the methods. But I don't necessary think that I need the control, because I'll be testing implementation details and in the cases I'll need it I now see that maybe I should change the method itself.

Comment: Yes normally it should be done. It´s a common way to seperate code in this way. The benefits are more control, it is better readable and understandable and you can reuse your code easier.
If you want show us your code that we can tell you if you should do it or not.

Comment: You can find the method in question it [TestsService](https://github.com/KristiyanVachev/Leaf/blob/master/src/Leaf.Services/Noit/TestsService.cs) as SendAnswer, and [TestService](https://github.com/KristiyanVachev/Leaf/blob/master/src/Leaf.Services/Noit/TestService.cs) is the helper class in which I've split the methods. I'm currently refactoring it and am thinking of merging them into one class.

Comment: Now to which class/classes does your question refer? Did you already split the code up or shell i have a look at one class to tell you if spliting up is usefull?

Comment: As i said above i still suggest you to keep it refactored. This is the professional way to go. And in the future when you want to reuse your code you will be happy that you kept it seperated.

Comment: Arent you happy with the result? But if you are please accept the answer.